# Using OpenCV library in VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to use the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) library in order to load an image in a VB window. I am using [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), I have no idea how to add OpenCV references into my VB.NET project!

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: OpenCV is for unmanaged languages such as C or C++/Win32. Use the managed [**EmguCV**](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) wrapper instead.

Comment: So, if I understand you well, it is impossible to integrate OpenCV directly in .NET environnement. Should I absolutly use the EmguCV wrapper ?

Comment: Yes it is impossible since C# and VB.NET (etc.) don't understand the native machine code. But what's wrong with using a wrapper? A wrapper is usually designed very similar to the base library, and in the end it calls the methods in the base library anyway.

Comment: If you know your way around C++ and/or C++/CLI you can create your own wrapper for the OpenCV methods, structures and classes that you need.

Comment: Great ! thanks a lot, you saved me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.Net/
and then replace your 'using ??' with: Imports OpenCV.Net